# Automatically update drupal nodes at submit time

Tags: drupal-6

Is it possible to automatically update the drupal node's content at submit time?

When adding images to the node, they are stored as <img src="http://myserver/sites/....">

However, we frequently distribute the content to customer servers, and 'myserver' is therefore incorrect. If I used <img src="/sites/...."> can anyone foresee any issues (drupal is always installed at the root level).

If this does not cause any issues, can it be automated, so when any new content is added, it scans for 'http://myserver/sites' and replaces with '/sites' ?

Thanks in advance,

Martin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the gritty details really depend on how you are uploading images... either with the default [Upload module](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--upload--upload.module/6) or a combination of [FileField](http://drupal.org/project/filefield) and [ImageField](http://drupal.org/project/imagefield) (I'd recommend the latter).

Either way.. You should be able to make adjustments to the node automatically with an implementation of [hook_nodeapi()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_nodeapi/6) (when $op == 'presave').  Doing so will require a [custom module](http://drupal.org/node/231276), but don't be deterred by that, it's pretty straightforward to set up.

To see what's going on during that hook, so you can make sure that you're file info is there and ready to be edited.. do this (**on a development server!**):

```
drupal_set_message("<pre>".print_r($node,true)."</pre>")
```

That should show you what's going on in the $node object, and if you can find the filepath you should be able to edit it before it gets into the database.

You could also just alter the output with the same hook, when $op=='view'.

Comment: +1 This shouldn't be difficult to do with a tiny custom module.